# Is SameSite=None and Secure=1 flag on cookie is a security threat in terms of CSRF.?

Tags: php, google-chrome, cookies, session-cookies

Due to recent changes in Chrome, my website Payment Gateway was broken. To fix it I was forced to set my cookie parameters as SameSite=None and Secure=1 like the screenshot below from Mozilla Developer Doc:

[image]

What my doubt is, is this opening a potential CSRF threat to the website? I don't have any walkaround for this. Because I want to preserve my session cookie when the customer goes for the bank website for 3D secure validation and returns to complete the order. Changing these flags on my cookie fixes those issues.